RegExp for checking whole decimal numbers mixed with special chars
I need a RegExp to test strings that should consist of the valid whole decimal numbers including zero (0, 1, 12, 123, but not 00 or 0123) mixed with a special character (such as x) in free occurrences:
Examples of valid strings:
0, 1, 123, x, xx, x0, 0x, x0x, 0x0, xx123x0, x1000xx5xxx, ...
Invalid: 00, x00, 01, x01, ... and basically all including wrong numbers (starting with 0 but not being a zero).
I came up with the following:
new RegExp('^0?$|^((?!0)[0-9]+|x0$|0x|x+)+$')

Unfortunately, it does not work 100%, e.g. a valid string is not accepted: 0x0.
Thanks for any help!

Please clarify, which of these given examples values it is actually supposed to match, and which not.

@CBroe Updated, all examples were valid, so I added some invalid examples too

It's solved already, but one more idea: ^\b(?:(?:x|^)(?:0|[1-9]\d*)?)+$

why is 0x0 valid?

@bobblebubble Neat! Works as well, thanks!

@DuesserBaest 0 (zero) is a valid number and two of them are mixed with one x - matches the definition

aah now i get it. i thought its supposed to be a single number disrupted by x's

I got this Regular Expression to work with each of your examples:
new RegExp('^(((?<![0-9])([1-9][0-9]*)?[0-9]?)x*)+$')

I should note that it relies on a "negative lookbehind", which might not be supported by older environments. I have yet to run into any compatibility issues when using it in a modern browser.
RegExr.com can be quite helpful for visually explaining each part of a Regular Expression.

This works perfectly, thanks! My runtime is Node, so I have no problem with compatibility.

I'm glad that I could find a working solution for you!

An idea without use of lookarounds:
^\b(?:(?:x|^)(?:0|[1-9]\d*)?)+$

See this demo at regex101
A word boundary \b at ^ start gets used to disallow empty matches (drop if such are wanted). The pattern is self-explanatory. Used are non-capture groups, alternation and basic quantifiers.

really elegant answer!

I think this is what you want:
new RegExp('(^0(x\d+)?$)|(^[1-9]\d*$)')


Unfortunately, this does not work for almost all cases, for instance, it does not match a valid string x0 but it does match invalid strings 0x00 and 0x01
